# Does a surface of genus 2 admit a nonzero vector field?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does a surface of genus 2 admit a nonzero vector field?

A surface of genus 2 could be the double torus or a sphere $S^2$, correct?

I'm really not good with vector fields so I need help with this one.  I tried doing some research and didn't have any luck. Thanks.

Comment: A surface of genus 2 is, by definition, the same thing as the "double torus". A manifold that carries a nonzero vector field necessarily has Euler characteristic zero, so no.

Comment: The terminology in the question isn't completely clear, but if "nonzero vector field" is intended to mean "nowhere zero, continuous vector field", then Mike Miller's comment gives the correct answer (and should probably be an answer rather than a comment).

Comment: So since the euler characteristic of a double torus is -2, then it doesn't admit a nonzero vector field because a nonzero vector field has euler characteristic of zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: A manifold admits a non-zero vector field if and only if the Euler characteristic is zero. The only orientable surface with euler characteristic zero is the torus. A genus 2 surface has euler characteristic $-2$ so it does not have a vector field without zeroes.